# how can I loop through the payload and search within the same payload in another array with similar structure and alter matches

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have entered the payload as shown below, but I have to replace the values ​​of "labelnumber" with the similar number from the main line array with the matches "payload.lines.number = payload.notification.body.lines.number" that are inside the line array inside the notification element, can anyone help me how can we replace it.

**input payload**

```
{
  "date": "2022-11-15T19:24:36.871Z",
  "lines": [
  {
    "number": "123",
    "labelnumber":"ABC",
    "received": "2022-11-15T19:30:17.955Z"
  },
  {
    "number": "456",
    "labelnumber":"DFG",
    "received": "2022-11-15T19:30:57.426Z"
  },
  {
    "number": "789",
    "labelnumber":"HIJ",
    "received": "2022-11-15T19:31:49.042Z"
  }
 ],
 "notification":{
   "body":{
        "date": "2022-11-15T19:24:36.871Z",
        "lines": [
          {
            "number": "123",
            "labelnumber":"",
            "received": "2022-11-15T19:30:17.955Z"
          },
          {
            "number": "123",
            "labelnumber":"",
            "received": "2022-11-15T19:30:57.426Z"
          },
          {
            "number": "456",
            "labelnumber":"",
            "received": "2022-11-15T19:31:49.042Z"
          },
          {
            "number": "789",
            "labelnumber":"",
            "received": "2022-11-15T19:31:49.042Z"
          },
          {
            "number": "789",
            "labelnumber":"",
            "received": "2022-11-15T19:31:49.042Z"
          }
        ]
        }
      }
   }
```

**expected payload**

```
{
  "date": "2022-11-15T19:24:36.871Z",
  "lines": [
  {
    "number": "123",
    "labelnumber":"ABC",
    "received": "2022-11-15T19:30:17.955Z"
  },
  {
    "number": "456",
    "labelnumber":"DFG",
    "received": "2022-11-15T19:30:57.426Z"
  },
  {
    "number": "789",
    "labelnumber":"HIJ",
    "received": "2022-11-15T19:31:49.042Z"
  }
 ],
 "notification":{
   "body":{
        "date": "2022-11-15T19:24:36.871Z",
        "lines": [
          {
            "number": "123",
            "labelnumber":"ABC",
            "received": "2022-11-15T19:30:17.955Z"
          },
          {
            "number": "123",
            "labelnumber":"ABC",
            "received": "2022-11-15T19:30:57.426Z"
          },
          {
            "number": "456",
            "labelnumber":"DFG",
            "received": "2022-11-15T19:31:49.042Z"
          },
          {
            "number": "789",
            "labelnumber":"HIJ",
            "received": "2022-11-15T19:31:49.042Z"
          },
          {
            "number": "789",
            "labelnumber":"HIJ",
            "received": "2022-11-15T19:31:49.042Z"
          }
        ]
        }
      }
   }
```

As you can see in this example, I need to loop through the main row array and find the matches within the notification array and assign the corresponding value.

**NOTE: maybe in the notification.body has many elements and I don't need to change them and I don't know the name of its elements, in this case it only has "date" but I need to keep them as they are.**

Answer (score 2):

With the update operator you can update only the keys that you want. This solution assumes that all the number values are defined in `payload.lines`.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
    case lines at .notification.body.lines -> lines map ((item, index) ->  
        item update {
            case .labelnumber -> (payload.lines filter ($.number == item.number))[0].labelnumber
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting reference line Array to Hashmap will help replace values efficiently instead of looping every time. Following code will  work

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var lineMap = {(payload.lines map {
    ($.number) : $.labelnumber
})}
var modifiedLines = (payload.notification.body.lines map ((item, index) -> {
    data : item mapObject ((value, key, dataindex) -> {
        (key) : if (key ~= 'labelnumber') lineMap[item.number] else value
    })
})).data 
---
(payload - 'notification') ++ 
{
    "notification":{
        "body":{
            "lines": modifiedLines
        }
    }
}
```

Update : with updated requirement body can have any fields

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
output application/json
var lineMap = {(payload.lines map {
    ($.number) : $.labelnumber
})}
var modifiedLines = payload.notification.body.lines map ((item, index) -> item update 'labelnumber' with  lineMap[item.number]) 
var body = (payload.notification.body - 'lines') ++ {lines : modifiedLines}
---
(payload - 'notification') ++ 
{
    "notification":{
        "body": body
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry not worked because maybe in notification.body has a lot of element and i dont need to change and i dont know its elements name, in this case only has "date"

Comment: To be sure that a given implementation performs faster or more efficiently you need to actually test it. You can not just assume the implementation.